# Intellij 12+: is there a way to set default code style?

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, file-extension, file-format, intellij-idea

I work with a lot of javascript files that are not suffixed by ".js", so Intellij renders no code style at all (no coloration or auto-complete) unless I put `<script>` tags around the code (which won't work). Is there a way in the Code Style menu to set my default code style to javascript for files on which intellij is unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `File -> Settings -> File Types` there in `Recognize File Types` panel choose **JavaScript files** and then add new Wildcard for it.

[image]

Hope I solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you, this is the right answer, though I still have a couple issues. When I do this, intelliJ runs out of memory and has to re-index all my files on restart! I really wish intelliJ could mark up files as I open them rather than all at once when I set a new rule. Also, the server-side code I have mixed in with the JS messes up the file's formatting, but I guess that's to be expected.

Comment: @Amalgovinus you can select each file individually. In context menu of the file, choose `Accociate with File type`. But this [feature](http://goo.gl/j6IVkU) work not all files without extension, [seem bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-79574).